create EVP_PKEY c++
I have private key, but i don't know how get EVP_PKEY in C++,can you help me?
int rsaEvpEncrypt(EVP_PKEY* pkey, const char* data) {
    EVP_PKEY_CTX* ctx = NULL;
    //EVP_PKEY * pkey = NULL;
    unsigned char* encrypted = NULL;
    size_t outlen = 0;
    const size_t inlen = strlen(data);

    printf("Print %d", 1);
    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, NULL);
    printf("Print %d", 2);
    if (!ctx) {
        return 1000;
    }

    // Init encryption context.
    if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init(ctx) <= 0) { // <-SEGFAULT LINE
        return 5;
    }

    printf("Print %d", 3);
    // Defines padding
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) <= 0) {
        return 6;
    }

    // Evaluating size for encrypted buffer and encrypting
    if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt(ctx, NULL, &outlen, (const unsigned char*)data, inlen) <= 0) {
        return 7;
    }

    encrypted = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(outlen);
    printf("Print %d", 5);
    if (!encrypted) {
        return 8;
    }

    printf("Print %d", 6);
    if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt(ctx, encrypted, &outlen, (const unsigned char*)data, inlen) <= 0) {
        return 9;
    }
}

I don't know it is correctrly or not.
I try find in google, but my  attemps, were not successful

Why are you passing in NULL for the engine parameter of EVP_PKEY_CTX_new()?

What I must write?

How is rsaEvpEncrypt() being called? Are you sure the EVP_PKEY is valid? Please provide a [mcve]
